# Como enviar una alerta de BD Oracle a Java web

Tags: java, base-de-datos, oracle, plsql

vengo con una pregunta que me ha dado un par de vueltas....

Tengo una app web en Java que entre muchas cosas, mantiene el stock de productos, la base de datos Oracle tiene la tabla(imagen) donde persisten los datos.

Entonces mi consulta es: **Puedo mediante un trigger enviar una alerta de poco stock(stock_critico) a la aplicación, creando un listener en la app?**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si está mal mi concepto de listener por favor diganmelo.

Algún tutorial o documento donde pueda hacer lo que necesito???

Agradezco de antemano....

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que usar `JMS` en oracle y java. Nunca lo he hecho yo, pero es algo así:
Tienes que crear un `Java Store Procedure` en oracle que funcione como `productor de JMS` y que publique el mensaje que deseas (esto es similar a los `servidores de colas de mensajes`[de hecho JMS es una abstracción/generalización de los servidores de colas]). En el trigger invocas a este `Java Store Procedure`.
Del lado de la aplicación web tienes que crear un `consumidor JMS o susbscriptor` que lea dicho mensaje y actualice la aplicación con el dato que deseas.

[Como empezar con JMS de oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/introjms-1577110.html) y la [introduccion a JMS de Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28420/jm_create.htm#i1005706) te puede ayudar.

**Esto es lo que se que existe para hacer lo que quieres, pero repito nunca lo he realizado yo.**